# Convert C# awaited method to Mono (Unity3D)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I trying to port my Windows Phone game to Unity, and having some problems with the async server calls I've made:

```
public static async Task<T> Get<T>(String path)
{
    HttpClient client = CreateHttpClient();

    var clientResponse = await client.GetAsync(Config.SERVER_URL + path);

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(await clientResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
}
```

I've got the following in Unity script, but this trows all kinds of crazy:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetAnonymous<T>(string path)
{
  WWW www = new WWW(SERVER_URL + path);

  yield return (T)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(www.text);
}
```

It states that Object ref not set to an instance of an object, when I try to access properties of the object

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the **WWW** class to finish the request.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetAnonymous<T>(string path)
{
  WWW www = new WWW(SERVER_URL + path);

  yield return www;

  return (T)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(www.text)
}
```

You can read some more about the WWW class [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.html).

Comment: If i put yield www; it states a error telling me a local var named www is already defined in this scope :/

Comment: sorry, you should have yield return www; I've edited my answer.

Comment: thank you for your response, but i still have problems. It halts on the yield return www telling me "Cannot implicitly convert type WWW to T... seems return returns the method :) still in limbo :/

Comment: yup, that's because you're trying to return a WWW type when T is required, try to remove the type from IEnumerable,but this means that you need to do an explicit cast when calling GetAnonymous